# Dividing space into homogeneous connected areas

Tags: software-recommendations, algorithm, spatial-analysis, redistricting

Is there an algorithm (or software) for splitting a map into K connected areas such that the within-area variance of some variable is minimised, and the between-area variance of that variable is maximised?

This seems like it'd be a fairly common problem. For example, one might want to do this sort of thing if one wanted to draw homogeneous electoral districts.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include details of what you've actually tried, and what happens when you try it.